# how to avoid full table scan for my MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me for changes in this query

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand 
SET APA_Pended_Demand.genericDemandId=( 
    SELECT APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId  
    FROM APA_Generic_Demand_Details  
    WHERE APA_Generic_Demand_Details.demandID=APA_Pended_Demand.demandID  
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.isPend = 1 
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId != ''  
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId IS NOT NULL  
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.status < 300
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

The indexing given for the table is

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `apgnricdemnddetils_bndnresn` (`abandonReason`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddetils_prdcttype` (`productType`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddtils_srcereqrle` (`sourceReqRole`),
 KEY `apgnericdemnddetils_methdin` (`methodIn`),
 KEY `IX1_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`customerReference`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX2_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`schemeReference`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX3_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX4_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`initiator`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX5_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX7_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX8_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`initiator`,`status`) USING BTREE,
```

The query is not using the index.I tried for explain for the query and it shows type as All and keys as None. So is there anyway to get it use the index or do we need to change the query?

Answer (score 1):

Use an update join instead:

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand t1
INNER JOIN APA_Generic_Demand_Details t2
    ON t1.demandID = t2.demandID
SET t1.genericDemandId = t2.genericDemandId
WHERE t1.isPend = 1 AND
      COALESCE(t2.genericDemandId, '') != '' AND
      t1.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP() AND
      t2.status < 300 AND
      t1.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

Comment: Hi Tim,Thank you so much

Comment: @sravan Is there any reason why you removed this as a correct answer?